# since I installed Xcode 7.1.1 and updatet on osx 10.11.1 I get a git error

Tags: xcode, git, macos, github, cocoapods

Like mentioned in the topic I updated xcode to version 7.1.1 and osx to version 10.11.1 after that I received errors when trying to compile a project with cocoa pods inside. When I try to run "pod install" I receive:

Creating shallow clone of spec repo `master` from `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git`
[!] Unable to add a source with url `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` named `master`.
You can try adding it manually in `~/.cocoapods/repos` or via `pod repo add`.

I tried to add the repo manually but then I get:

[!] /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master

sh: line 1:  3405 Segmentation fault: 11  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk / -find git 2> /dev/null
git: error: unable to find utility "git", not a developer tool or in PATH

when I tried to use "git --version" I get:

sh: line 1:  3408 Segmentation fault: 11  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk / -find git 2> /dev/null
git: error: unable to find utility "git", not a developer tool or in PATH

So I tried to add the PATH manually but i weren't able get it work 
my echo $PATH delivers:

/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

and my echo $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:

/usr/local/mysql/lib/

Does anyone have a clue how i can fix that problem?

thank you very much :)

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to solve the problem but i think i new what caused the Trouble. Its possible that my python 3.4 and python 2.7 installations screwed something badly up in my system. To solve everything I made a Time Machine backup and reseted the whole system and now everything is working fine again. Thank the Lord haha :)

Answer (score 1):

Today I had the same error.

1) `cd ~/.cocoapods/repos`

2) `git clone git://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master` 
(use **git** protocol, I failed when try to do that via https)

3) `pod install --no-repo-update --verbose`

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have the exact same issue with cocoapods, but I also got the git error after updating to Xcode 7.1.1 (still on OSX 10.10.5):

```
error: unable to find utility "git", not a developer tool or in PATH
```

Simply restarting the terminal fixed the problem for me.